# How to know when a record was created using a page layout within a trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, page-layout, admin

Is there a way to know when a record was created using the standard Sf UI instead of using code/declarative tools?

Comment: I am not sure that there is a way to distinguish it. 
You can create `Source__c` field (picklist), which will be set to e.g "Code" when created by code/declarative tools, and read-only on the page layout (set to e.g."UI Form").

Comment: Yes that was what I was thinking too @PiotrGajek. :) I was wondering if there was any another way because I don't know the codebase and there is many ways to create a case in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same doubt, and I solved it by creating a field of type picklist in the object in question. This field can be called for example "Created via page layout", and must have only one value available, for example "Yes".

[image]

Picklist values:

[image]

Then you need to make the field required only at the page layout level:

[image]

This should be enough, when the user creates a record through the page layout, by default, and without the possibility of unchecking (since it only has one value available and it is required), the value will be "Yes" or " SI", in the case of the image.
When the record enters through a different source than the page layout, it will be null, that way you can ask in the trigger if the field has the value "Yes" or null, to know if it was created or not by page layout.